# Rally Query of Risks associated with all WorkItems that roll up to a Parent (i.e., Portfolio Item Investment)

Tags: rally

I have a Portfolio Item Investment that has many epics, features, and stories associated with it.  I want to pull a list of all risks that are associated with any work items (investment, epic, feature, story) that ultimately roll up to that investment.

I am using a query app to return a list of Risks and have success returning risks associated with the investment directly.  However, I cannot figure out how to properly parse the query so that it returns the risks associated with an epic under that investment, or a feature, or a story.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
(((State != "Closed") AND ((WorkItemsAffected.FormattedID = "I890") OR (WorkItemsAffected.FormattedID.Parent = "I890")))
```

**Note that I have listed Parent at the end because I receive a Parse error if I place it before FormattedID.  When it is at the end I do not receive an error, but the results do not list the risk I expect to see**

If I write the code as follows, I can see the risk, but I have too many epics, features, stories under this investment and it is not feasible to list each of those in one long nested query).

```
(((State != "Closed") AND ((WorkItemsAffected.FormattedID = "I890") OR (WorkItemsAffected.FormattedID = "E19230")))
```

Appreciate any help! :)

Answer (score 0):

The parse error is due to the fact that `WorkItemsAffected` is a collection of `RankableArtifact` objects which don't have a Parent field ([You can see this in the WSAPI Docs](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/)). So unfortunately there isn't an easy way to search for risks on a parent/child relationship basis in this manner.

Off the top of my head, the best approach programmatically would probably be to load the Investment and its hierarchy of children and then load any risks found on those artifacts individually and then display them in a grid. This is something you'd need to do in a custom app, as it's more involved than writing out a simple query.

A non-programmatic approach that may or may not be sufficient is to use the [Custom Grid with Deep Export app](https://github.com/RallyTechServices/custom-grid-with-deep-export). This would allow you to add Risks as a column in the grid, and then drill-down to see the full hierarchy of an individual Investment. You should be able to then click on a cell in the risk column to view a popup grid of risks associated with each artifact. There is export functionality but I'm not sure if it properly exports the risk field. That might require some additional tweaking of the app code.

Another more manual option would be to go through and add the Investment artifact to any risk found within the hierarchy or use tags to group certain risks together and then query/filter by tags (but of course this is far from ideal).